How to Run a Node.js App in NSJail on WSL?
I'm currently working with nsjail.
After setting up nsjail in Ubuntu WSL on Windows I'm trying to run a Node app in nsjail. I created a Node app then add nsjail-config.cfg:
name: "nodejs-jail"
mode: ONCE
hostname: "NODEJS-JAIL"
exec_bin {
    path: "/usr/bin/node"
    arg0: "node"
    arg: "/mnt/c/Users/myusername/nsjailnodeapp/index.js"
}

Then I run this command:
sudo nsjail --config mnt/c/Users/ktbinh2003/nsjailnodeapp/nsjail-config.cfg

It always returns this error, but /urs/bin/node already exists when I run which node:
[E][2024-12-17T08:04:19+0000][1] newProc():232 execve('/usr/bin/node') failed: No such file or directory
[F][2024-12-17T08:04:19+0000][1] runChild():485 Launching child process failed
[W][2024-12-17T08:04:19+0000][12746] runChild():505 Received error message from the child process before it has been executed
[E][2024-12-17T08:04:19+0000][12746] standaloneMode():275 Couldn't launch the child process

I think the problem is mapping file system of WSL, but don't know how to fix or do anything.
